# What F# type translates to a C# record type?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

When consumed from a C# caller the record types from F# don't seem to map directly to C# record types. Is there any alternative type in F# that translates directly to a C# record type?

Comment: I think the answer is no. Both C# and F# record types are compiled into plain old class types, so there's no direct mapping between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# record proposal diverges from F#'s implementation, and while there is no current way to use the `with` keyword in C#, there are issues tracking the roadmap to reconcile both ([903](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/903) and [904](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/904) on Github).